# .bat file to automatically connect to VPN and add a route in Windows 7

Tags: vpn, route

I can establish VPN connection using RASDIAL command. But how do I add a route to 192.168.254.0/24 automatically after VPN is connected? Each time after VPN connection is established, Windows could assign different interface ID to the VPN connection (the IF parameter to the ROUTE command).

I can do that manually using the following method. ROUTE PRINT command shows a list of interfaces, I can write down an interface ID for the VPN (42 for example) and then issue a command

```
route ADD 192.168.254.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.200 IF 42
```

But how can I do this automatically in the .bat file?

I'm using PPTP VPN (it cannot automatically push routing to client).

Since interface ID is different each time VPN connects, I cannot use route -p (add a persistent route on clients). BTW, this is not a good solution, since VPN connection is sometimes used on office staff's notebooks. Sometimes their notebooks are part of the network, that is already a part of VPN and sometimes they establish VPN connection themselves.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293629/script-for-add-route) is a solution for PowerShell and it's ok for me. But I'm curious, can the same be done via simple .bat file?

Comment: You can also try to use the option 121 of dhcp server to automatically push routes to clients?

Comment: Yea, but I just think, are .bat files powerful enough to do the task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried to find any good working solution too and failed and after that I decided to write it by myself.
You can use it if you still need it.
http://www.latestbit.com/winvpnhelper

Comment: Miraculous!!! ;)

Comment: I hope it's working very well for you. If you have any issues please inform me. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo of
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('IPCONFIG ^|FIND "IP" ^|FIND "192.168.99"') do set _IP=%%a 
set GW=%_IP:~1% 
echo %GW%
route add 192.168.99.0 mask 255.255.255.0 %GW% 
route add 192.168.236.0 mask 255.255.255.0 %GW%
```

Comment: Please add some comments explaining what your script does and why it would help OP instead of just posting a bunch of code.